# Should I give my colleague a souvenir I got from a holiday in a place with e.g. epidemic outbreak?

Tags: holidays, gifts

For example, if I traveled to Asia (such as Japan or Shanghai, China) early this winter and brought back some small souvenirs intended for my colleagues. Should I refrain from giving them to my colleagues and bosses due to their fear over coronavirus?

Would it make a difference if I was at the epicenter of the virus outbreak (Wuhan, China in this example)?

(Assuming I was not infected by coronavirus. The probability the gift is infected with the virus is very low since e.g. the time when I was in Asia is before the complete outbreak of the virus (e.g. at the end of last year).)

Note: I am looking for a cultural answer.

The example is used for illustration. My question is just that should I give my colleagues souvenir from a region which is currently feared globally due to epidemics even when I am very sure that the gift is very likely to be not infected?

I am asking this because someone I know give their colleagues souvenirs from Middle East during a MERS outbreak, which their colleagues gladly accepted. I am not sure whether it is appropriate after the cronovirus outbreak.

Comment: Are you looking for a medical opinion on whether or not a virus could be contracted from such a gift? Or are you looking for a cultural answer on whether or not such a gift would be acceptable in the workplace setting?

Comment: [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I am looking for a cultural answer.

Comment: Is this an actual situation you face? Right now, it's posed as a purely hypothetical question (which isn't really a good fit for this format). For example, what was the actual location that you visited? First you ask about Japan, then you ask abut China in general, then you ask about Wuhan in particular.

Comment: Even with the edit, I have to repeat my original objection that this is posed as a purely hypothetical, open-ended question. Is this an actual situation you face, or is it just a hypothetical "what-if" question? Can you edit to include the particulars of a concrete situation so that we can answer that?

Comment: My question is just: Should I give my colleagues souvenir from a region which is currently feared globally due to epidemics even when I am very sure that the gift is very likely to be not infected (see the edit)? Can you judge whether the gift is infected from "more concrete information"?

Comment: For a cultural standpoint, I think it's okay. However, I would strongly advise you from doing this due to the coronavirus outbreak. There is no definitive choice that you have presented here so I don't think we can truly answer this. Of course it would make a difference if you were in China versus Japan. One country has over 28000 people infected, one has not nearly as much infected. One has more risk, one has less risk. I'm not sure how you can _guarantee_ yourself from getting the coronavirus unless you are very good at isolating yourself from other people entirely.

Comment: Think about this from your colleagues' perspective as well. Would you accept a gift from China during this pandemic?

Comment: @KingDuken I would look at the others' reaction

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica I find your objection rather unfounded. Would you be able to judge whether the gift is infected from "more concrete information"?

Comment: Is this an actual situation that you face, or is it purely hypothetical? If it's an actual situation, you should tell us where the gift is actually from, not just where it *might* be from. For example, is the gift actually from Wuhan or not?

Comment: I noticed your title implies that you _already have the gift_ by saying "I got", which is past tense. But in your question you're asking about some what-if scenarios. This is kind of confusing.

Comment: @KingDuken My point exactly. It's unclear if the OP is asking a purely hypothetical question (which would be [off-topic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)) or if they're asking about an actual, concrete situation. If they're asking about an actual situation, they should describe the actual situation (not just give us a hypothetical "what-if" scenario).

Comment: You should be more specific about where the gift came from. China is a huge place, and Japan is a separate island...

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica I am quite sure that my question is "practical and answerable" and hence is not off-topic. Hypothetical or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @Mars Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: No, hypothetical questions are most definitely [of-topic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). You should ask about situations that you actually face.

Comment: @Aqqqq Japan and Shanghai are two totally different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is just that should I give my colleagues souvenir from a region which is currently feared globally due to epidemics even when I am very sure that the gift is very likely to be not infected?

No, you should not.

The only information that your colleagues will have is that the gift came from the "feared" region.  You may be very sure that the gift is not infected but your colleagues have nothing to go by other than your word.  Even if they absolutely trust that you would not attempt to harm them, they have no way of knowing if the gift is infected unless some sort of tests are performed to confirm either way.  Even mentioning that you were in the feared region may be enough to cause a panic for some of your colleagues.  The bottom line, do not attempt to give them gifts from that area until the fears surrounding that area have been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: I am looking for a cultural answer.

Forget the cultural aspect, if you suspect such souvenir could be infected you should not give it away and dispose it immediately in an appropriate way (or even contact Health authorities).

If you want a cultural aspect of this, I am positive that in *any* culture health is something good and valuable. Thus, **gifting someone a thing that could endanger their health is undesirable in any culture.**